# Why won't my iPad apps sync when connected to my computer?

Tags: ipad, applications, data-synchronization

I have always updated my application on iTunes and then let them sync to the iPad.

Since I installed iOS 10.3.3, the apps no longer sync. I have rebooted the device. I have attempted to sync many times.

The App Store on the iPad shows pending updates, but they never install.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your sync connection usb or [wifi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249404/ipad-wont-sync)?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to try first is to reset your privacy and location preferences. You will then be asked to trust the iTunes/computer drivers (and asked to set privacy settings elsewhere as they come up).

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202778

At that point, the issue is almost certainly on the computer end with iTunes or iTunes settings or the os/usb hardware and drivers. Starting with a review of iTunes settings and looking for specific sync errors would be good to start.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201253

Comment: Resetting the privacy settings in the iPad yielded no results.

Comment: And I'm not missing anything in iTunes on my computer.

Comment: You’ll probably have to go through the second article step by step then. Can you even install a file after verifying steps 1, 2, 3 of HT20135? If so, following the article and all the links should get you to a specific failure code or step to fix.